# Dynamics CRM 2011 - WCF error

Tags: wcf, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to get to grips with MS Dynamics CRM 2011. I have have the beta installed on a VM and things look pretty good - some great new features etc.

However I am getting an exception when trying to connect to the new XRMServices (updated 2011 WCF web services)

```
 Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service    
 '/organame/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc' cannot be activated due to an
 exception during compilation.  The exception message is:
 'System.ServiceModel.Description.UseRequestHeadersForMetadataAddressBehavior'. 
 This collection only supports one instance of each type.
 Parameter name: item. ---> System.ArgumentException: The value could not be added to
 the collection, as the collection already contains an item of the same type: 
 'System.ServiceModel.Description.UseRequestHeadersForMetadataAddressBehavior'. 
 This collection only supports one instance of each type.
 Parameter name: item
```

The only reference to this exception I gave found suggests that it is caused by multiple bindings configured in IIS, which in my case I did have, but the problem persists even after removing them.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the same with RC?

Comment: I second that. While I haven't had any problems of this kind with the CTP or Beta versions, this might just be an issue that has been resolved in the RC.

Comment: Thanks - I will try upgrading and see if that fixes the issue.